# Should child comment be treated as separate table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, best-practices, constraint

I'm building a commenting system, currently my table indicates which comment is child with parent id in **1 table**, I would like to know what is the best way of doing this?

**Current Table Scheme (1 Table)**:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `child_idx` (`parent`,`id`),
  KEY `post_FK_idx` (`post`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_comment_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`post`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=158 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

#### Question:

1. Should I add a second table for the child and do a `JOIN` when retrieving The comments?
2. If child can be in 1 table, how should I delete all children when parent get deleted? (I have read about [Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), but that doesn't work on 1 table.)

#### Foreign Key:

When I create a Foreign Key on 1 table, it works and get created, but when I try to enter data I get the following error.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`App`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `child_comment_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`)
REFERENCES `comments` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)"
```

#### Statement:

```
INSERT INTO comments SET 
    parent = :parent,
    post = :post,   
    comment = :comment;
```

#### Screenshot of Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
INSERT INTO comments
SET parent = 0,
    post = 385,
    comment = 'Hello, World' ;
```

Do you have a row in `comments` with `id = 0`? If not, the error is what one would expect. Put `parent=NULL`, not `parent=0`, if you want a comment to not have a parent.